# Connect live server to local database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, deployment, server

for the past year I've been developing a Laravel app for a client which is about to go live. Now the client wants the **database to run on his own server in his office** (unfortunately not negotiable). Is that possible?

If someone could point me in a general direction, that would help me out a lot. Maybe there's already a solution specifically for Laravel, but I just don't know where to start looking.

Comment: in the base root of your `Laravel` project you should have a file named `.env` --  It should have all your environment variables in it including database host, username and password  ... In the `DB_HOST` parameter, put the IP address for his office.  It will be up to the IT person at his office to allow for port 3306 to point to the db server and accept traffic at that point.

Comment: " It will be up to the IT person at his office to allow for port 3306 to point to the db server and accept traffic at that point." Company would also have to need a static IP before that will work which not all internet providers provide.. @Zak .. Also you should use a SSL connection between the webserver and the remote MySQL server to prevent other to able to listing in on the data which are on the same network.

Comment: @RaymondNijland -- Good point!

Comment: @Robert Another thing to think about is, if that port is left open, without a stringent firewall and some crafty policies --  The database is open to brute force cracking.  It's worth noting that a VPN tunnel might be wise in this instance.

Comment: @Zak You can add firewall policies which only allow traffic from one IP on a port. And deny traffic from all other IP's, which is only safe on the TCP protocol because UDP protocol can be easy IP spoofed.. But a VPN or SSH tunnel would be a extra security layer on top of that.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. First I will present the list from tadman to the client. If he still wants to use his own database, I will come back to you :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a spectacularly bad idea, so document the risks and potential problems created by this approach and have the client **acknowledge them in writing**. These risks include:

- The server must be physically secured from unauthorized access.
- The server must be kept patched.
- The server must be have the screen locked at all times its not in use by authorized personnel, and protected with a reasonably robust password.

  - Where this password is not written on a post note stuck to the screen.
- The server must be on a battery backup system.

  - This battery backup system must be tested *under load* at least once per month.
  - This battery backup system *must* safely shut-down the server should the battery become nearly exhausted.
- The server must be backed up on a daily basis:

  - The backups must be stored off-site.
  - The backups must be encrypted using a reasonably robust *passphrase*.
- The server's backups must be tested monthly.
- The server's connection must be monitored for packet loss and other interruptions.
- The server and any associated infrastructure (routers, switches, cabling) must be covered by a comprehensive disaster recovery plan.

You'll want to specifically itemize that as the consultant you cannot be held liable for any disruption to business caused by a failure of the server, connection, or other infrastructure under the direct control of the client, that the client assumes *all risks*.

In short, there's a *lot* of reasons you can list here and formalize in a legally binding document. If the client re-thinks their decision after this point, great, you've got a solution. If they don't, it's their problem and their insurance that'll have to pay out when this goes horribly awry.

Comment: I agree that this idea is pretty bad, so thanks for giving me this beautiful list of reasons not to do it :) Who knows, maybe this will actually change his mind.

Comment: Clients that insist on "server hugging" (on-premise) usually don't realize how much work a cloud provider does to ensure a high level of service.